# Android Studio | Asynctask | JSON Receiving null object reference error when attempting to parse JSON

Tags: java, json, android-studio

As the title suggests, I'm having an issue parsing JSON data from a URL with an asynctask in Android Studio. I keep receiving a Null Object Reference error, however if I use the below code in an Eclipse Enterprise project (without the asynctask code, just a regular application), I'm able to parse the JSON just fine. Also, the internet works on my emulator, as I am able to access Google on the web browser. Could you guys point me in the right direction on how to overcome this issue? I have tried everything that I could think of, and I'm just confused because the code works in a regular Eclipse Java Application project, yet doesn't work in Android Studio.

Asynctask Code:
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_item);

```
        class CallDBQuery extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Item> {
            protected Item doInBackground(URL...url) {
                try {
                    URL urls = new   
                URL("XXX");

                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, 
    false);

                    //Item Items = mapper.readValue(urls, Item.class);

                    return mapper.readValue(urls, Item.class);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Item Items) {
                TextView fieldTxt = (TextView)   
                findViewById(R.id.View2);

       fieldTxt.setText(Items.getItems().get(0).GetTitle().toString());
            }
        }
        try {
            URL url = new 
                URL("XXX");

            new CallDBQuery().execute(url);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Note: Commented out the Items Item = mapper.readValue() part because I was 
receiving a "Redundant variable message", but even when I was using this bit of code, and returning "Items", I still received the Null Object Reference

JSON:

```
{"Items":[{"Email":"jared.hart1@gmail.com","Description":"Surface Pro 4  
for sale, in excellent condition, basically brand 
new!","Phone":"4077603835","Title":"Surface Pro 4","Id":"1"},
{"Email":null,"Description":null,"Phone":null,"Title":"Macbook 
Air","Id":"2"},{"Email":"jhart@radixx.com","Description":"Free Macbook 
Air, I promise","Phone":"3433215565","Title":"Lenovo 
Laptop","Id":"3"}]}
```

JSON Class Item:

```
public class Item {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<ItemDetails> Items = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

    public List<ItemDetails> getItems() {return this.Items;}
    public void setItems(List<ItemDetails> Items) {this.Items = Items;}
}
```

JSON Class ItemDetails:

```
public class ItemDetails {
    @JsonProperty
    private String Id;

    @JsonProperty
    private String Title;

    @JsonProperty
    private String Phone;

    @JsonProperty
    private String Email;

    @JsonProperty
    private String Description;

    public String GetId() {return this.Id;}
    public void SetId(String Id) {this.Id = Id;}

    public String GetTitle() {return this.Title;}
    public void SetTitle(String Title) {this.Title = Title;}

    public String GetPhone() {return this.Phone;}
    public void SetPhone(String Phone) {this.Phone = Phone;}

    public String GetEmail() {return this.Email;}
    public void SetEmail(String Email) {this.Email = Email;}

    public String GetDescription() {return this.Description;}
    public void SetDescription(String Description) {this.Description =  
    Description;}
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I'm not sure if this info will be helpful, but I'm coding on a Macbook Air, and using Wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! In my Manifest file, I had  inside the application tag. I debugged my application, and discovered that I was getting the Null value from the catch block of my code, due to an Internet Security Permission Exception. After adding the  code outside of the application tag, everything worked!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />